# How to set up Mongo DB on Mac?

Tags: macos, mongodb

How can I set Up Mongo DB on Mac. What are the required commands? Can any one of you write the steps for the creation of Mongo DB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

out of curiosity: did you try to google your question? there is a very nice guide on how to set up mongodb on os x right on mongodb's official website:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+OS+X

Comment: Thanks but I was scared of "sudo" command as some times it deletes some important file.

Comment: @Harsh Mehrotra, no, `sudo` never deletes important files; `sudo` will *let you* perform destructive commands on important files, but you can avoid destructive commands by thinking.

Comment: FWIW this is the first result when DuckDuckGo search for "install mongodb on macOS"

Answer (score 2):

Just run this command:  `sudo port install mongodb`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I find the console and the use of sudo a bit intimidating myself too.

I was having trouble getting MongoDB  to work on Mac as well, here are a couple of links that helped me:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iT0datgVcfs
- http://blog.troygrosfield.com/2011/03/21/installing-and-running-mongodb-on-a-mac/

I hope you find them useful.

Comment: The youtube link worked for me.